# prestashop mail customisation, and module translation

Tags: module, prestashop

i have two question

1 - i installed referral program module , and i would like to customise the referralprogram-invitation.html mail template 
so i putted the new template under : `prestashop_root/themes/my_theme/modules/referralprogram/mails/referralprogram-invitation.html`
 but i doesn't work !

2 - i would like to add some extra text to the program page of referral program module
so i copied the file already included with the module under 
           `prestashop_root/themes/my_theme/modules/referralprogram/translations/fr.php` and I added the new text translation in this form

> $_MODULE['<{referralprogram}prestashop>program_MD5'] = 'new text';

and it does not work?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You only forgot the language folder. Your mail templates must not be in :
   `prestashop_root/themes/my_theme/modules/referralprogram/mails/referralprogram-invitation.html`
   but in
   `prestashop_root/themes/my_theme/modules/referralprogram/mails/fr/referralprogram-invitation.html`
2. If you want to add text to the program page, you must:

   - First, make a copy of the file : `prestashop_root/modules/referralprogram/views/templates/front/program.tpl` to `prestashop_root/themes/my_theme/modules/referralprogram/views/templates/front/program.tpl`
   - Then, you need to modify this file and add the text you want, where you want. To be translatable, your text must be added like this `{l s='new text' mod='referralprogram'}`.
   - Finally, you need to translate this text via the Localization > Traductions page of your BO and not directly in the `fr.php` file.

Do not hesitate if you need more information,
Paul.